# Make one column into multiple columns in R

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
Name Result
X1   Red
X2   Blue
X2   Green
X3   Red
X2   Yellow
X3   Blue
```

and I would like the values in the "Name" column to turn into their own columns with their corresponding "Result" value

```
X1  X2     X3
Red NA     NA
NA  Blue   NA
NA  Green  NA 
NA  NA     Red
NA  Yellow NA
NA  NA     Blue
```

I've looked into some options in tidyr (such as separate), but I haven't had any luck.

any help is appreciated. thank you :)

Comment: Try with `library(tidyr); spread(df1, Name, Result)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create a row number and then `spread`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   spread(Name, Result) %>%
   select(-rn)
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much :)